# Hibernate JPQL Constructor Expression doesn't work with OneToMany field

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa, jpql

When I try to use a constructor expression in a JPQL query

```
class CompanyProjection {
    String name;
    List<Employee> employees;

    public CompanyProjection (String name, List<Employee> employees) {
        ...
    }    
}

class Company {
    String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    List<Employee> employees;
}

class Employee {
     @ManyToOne
     Company company;
}
```

`select com.foo.CompanyProjection(c.name, c.employees) from Company c`

I get a `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.foo.CompanyProjection]. Expected arguments are: java.lang.String, com.foo.Employee[........]`

From the stacktrace above, I understand that Hibernate expects the second constructor argument to have an Employee.class type instead of the List.class.

But `c.employees` is actually a List. I don't understand if it is a bug in hibernate, or if I'm misusing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User error.

Using multi-valued fields in a SELECT clause of JPQL is ILLEGAL syntax. See the [JPQL BNF](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/query.html#jpql_bnf).

Comment: Ok I didn't know it was illegal, thanks for your answer ! :)